# How to use <layout> tag in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-databinding

I need to know how to use layout tag in android xml file. I know it is used for data binding but I do not have complete knowledge on this. Please let me know if anyone can help me in same.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#data_binding_layout_files

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `<layout>` tag must be the root tag when you are using `DataBinding`. Doing so you are telling the compiler that you are using `DataBinding` and your layout will have special tags like `<variable>` or `<import>`, so you have to embed your layout within that tag.

In short, you need to use the `<layout>` tag whenever you are using `DataBinding` for the compiler to understand the special tags and generate the `DataBinding` class with the right variables and methods.

If you have a layout like this (**layout_data_binding.xml**):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.firstName}"/>
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.lastName}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

It is based on what is inside the `<layout>` tag to create the `LayoutDataBinding` class (**auto-generated**) with the `User` variable and its getters and setters.