# Android resource compilation failed even after swapping attributes

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

Following is my `fragment_rate.xml` layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.ui.RateFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

When I compile this, I have this particular error:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output: /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_rate.xml:10: error: duplicate attribute.

Command: /home/sparker0i/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/d811e9cf0b30534b0c407565dcc71d36/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2 compile --legacy \
    -o \
    /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
    /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_rate.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #0
```

From this error message, line 10 resolves to the layout_width reference inside the FrameLayout. The strange fact is, when I swap the references of layout_height and layout_width, I still get the same error at line 10.

If there were a duplicate error, I should have got the error message on line 9 when I interchanged, but the error was still at line 10.

Please do help me.

PS. As strange as it sounds, there is also another user facing a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134938/android-resource-compilation-failedactivity-main-xml11-error-duplicate-attri)

EDIT1: Here is a more detailed error log:

```
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Failed to compile android resource '/home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_rate.xml'.
Output:  /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_rate.xml:10: error: duplicate attribute.

Command: /home/sparker0i/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/d811e9cf0b30534b0c407565dcc71d36/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
        /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_rate.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #2
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Failed to compile android resource '/home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_rate.xml'.
Output:  /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_rate.xml:10: error: duplicate attribute.

Command: /home/sparker0i/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/d811e9cf0b30534b0c407565dcc71d36/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
        /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_rate.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #2
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.close(WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.kt:67)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:324)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Failed to compile android resource '/home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_rate.xml'.
Output:  /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_rate.xml:10: error: duplicate attribute.

Command: /home/sparker0i/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/d811e9cf0b30534b0c407565dcc71d36/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
        /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_rate.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #2
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteCompileException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:44)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:28)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:34)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_rate.xml:10: error: duplicate attribute.

Command: /home/sparker0i/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/d811e9cf0b30534b0c407565dcc71d36/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
        /home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_rate.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #2
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doCompile(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:142)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:81)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:37)
    ... 10 more
```

EDIT2: Opened the layout file from the build folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>






    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:tag="layout/fragment_rate_0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" tools:context=".view.ui.RateFragment" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you open the XML as indicated in the filepath? (e.g. `/home/sparker0i/CurrencyConverter/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_rate.xml`)

Comment: Yes, check EDIT2. I don't know why the height and width parameters are being generated again @Edric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching on the `<layout>` tag, it appears to me that this tag is used for [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) as asked before [here (about the usage of the `<layout>` tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682525/how-to-use-layout-tag-in-android) and is explained in more detail at the [Android Developers documentation (about how to use such tags)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions).

So I'm what assuming here is that the properties in the `<layout>` tag are probably being internally passed down to the parent tag (which is `<FrameLayout>` in your case).

---

So, either you remove the `<layout>` tag and reassign those properties to the `<FrameLayout>` tag if you're not using Data Binding, or just remove all of the properties except the XML namespaces (or the `xmlns` attributes).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have given id to `<layout>` tag by mistake. After Removing that, problem is resolved.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout">

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cm1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: This helped me. But I had that id there for a WEEK and it wasn't a problem, it started crying after week.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by removing both `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

there must be some problem with your binding layout , correct your layout tag