# Element is not allowed here inside of ConstraintLayout when layout tag is used

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding

Is anyone having this strange problem? After enabling the data-binding and adding <layout>, all the child elements inside `ConstraintLayout` are no longer allowed.

[The screenshot showing the problem with <layout>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW1el.png)

If the problem occurs, the UI editor for ConstraintLayout will not work well.

[Missing attributes in UI editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XTUQ.png)

Without <layout>, everything looks normal

[Without layout tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0jmT.png)

[UI editor looks normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrLTs.png)

I tried to reproduce the problem by creating a new module. The results are the same. Does anyone have an idea?

Here is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: I guess your layout tag which is generally used if you have a thought of integrating data binding in your application. Whereas in your layout tag code you are not using <data> tag please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682525/how-to-use-layout-tag-in-android

Comment: doesn't matter if I use data tag or not.

Comment: I also got this issue when I was using constraint layout library version 1.1.3. I updated it version 2.0.0-beta3. Now it has fixed that issue.

Comment: In my case going to **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart** to do a more thorough cleanup worked like a charmed!