# Unresolved reference: Layout_ActivityBinding?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Create Mobile App for coursework on Kotlin. I ran into a problem that for some reason I can't nest a fragment in a FragmentContainerView. I couldn't find on the internet how to fix it.

Code in gradle

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.historicalsaratovnav"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding{enabled=true}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.0-alpha04"
}
```

Code layout

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Layout_Activity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:id="@+id/conteiner_fragment"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:menu="@menu/menu"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        >
        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Code file KT

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Binder
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View


class Layout_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: Layout_ActivityBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = Layout_ActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.Main.setOnClickListener {

            replaceFragment(Main_App_Screen_Fragment())

        }

        binding.List.setOnClickListener {

        }

        binding.Map.setOnClickListener {

        }

        binding.Profile.setOnClickListener {

---


        }

        binding.Settings.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Main_App_Screen_Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.conteiner_fragment, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Tried adding dependencies to Gradle, but nothing changed. Also, when I just created the binding, NameBinding was automatically generated for me. After that, I erased it and made it custom and I can’t do anything else because the application does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please do this in gradle

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, but it became possible to bind the binding of the main activity

Comment: It turned out to be a common IDE bug, everything worked, it remains to somehow connect the buttons from the navigation with the logic

Comment: You don't know how to access the buttons from the navigation?

  ```binding.bottomNavigationView.Main.setOnClickListener {

            replaceFragment(Main_App_Screen_Fragment())

        }```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a layout `.xml` named as `xyz_activity.xml`
then android will create a binding named `XyzActivityBinding`

suggest you to check your `.xml` name

Also add

```
 buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
 }
```

in your app build.gradle

Comment: I have a main activity and an additional activity on which items should be generated when navigation is used.

The fact that I have 2 activities can affect the binding. Since the main activity is immediately activated as a binding

Answer (score 0):

If this solution not helping you recommend you to try this solution once. You facing this error because of XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".settingModuleFragment.itemList.ItemsListActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarItemListLayout"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_fl"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/relative_rl">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:id="@+id/rv_ll"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_edTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/write_bg_color"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_24"
                    android:inputType="text" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_item"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noItems_Tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                style="@style/Label_Normal"
                android:text="@string/you_haven_t_added_any_items"/>
        </FrameLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_item_count_Tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/_0_0"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_amount_count_Tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

                android:text="@string/_0_0"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />
  

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

This is used if you need to use the  tag whenever you are using DataBinding for the compiler to understand the special tags and generate the DataBinding class with the right variables and methods.

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44682671/19674027

Comment: Use `<layout>` fir **viewBinding** and for dataBinding use `<data>` tag remaing of code will be as for your need like relative layout and linear layout.